# Can the change of sizeof(bool) really break old code?

Tags: c, gcc, abi

I have a C library which uses something like this:

```
struct Foo {
  const char *bar;
  bool important;
  struct Baz *baz;
}
```

Recently, I have used it in a project where `important` was supposed to be `false`, however, it evaluated as `true`. Looking on the memory layout (dump) of the structure, I have observed (from the beginning):

- 8 nonzero bytes
- 1 zero byte
- 7 nonzero bytes
- ...

Since my architecture is `x86_64`, I assume that:

- first 8 bytes was the `bar` member
- then there was the `important` member, which was expected to be 1B wide by the code that has set it (hence the 1 zero byte), but at the same time it was expected to be 4B wide (`sizeof int`) by the code that checked its truthiness (hence its evaluation as `true`)
- then there was padding up to 8B

If it is relevant, my platform is CentOS 7 with distribution version of GCC (4.8.5 RedHat).

---

My question is - can this really happen? Can an unsuspecting programmer encounter ABI breakage due to the change of sizeof(bool)? Further tips about:

- how to test it (MWE)
- which version of GCC / glibc / C standard brings this change
- how to avoid it

are welcome.

Comment: `at the same time it was expected to be 4B wide (sizeof int)` why? What has `int` to do with it? From the look of it, you have UB in your code.

Comment: AFAIK, C99's `<stdbool.h>` defines bool as int. Subsequent versions change this.

Comment: the only standard definition I know of for `bool` is to be a typedef of `_Bool`

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Guess I mixed it up with how people used to define `bool` before C99. I am confident that both the library and the project use `<stdbool.h>`, though.

Comment: I believe my statement did err by one nit: the standard actually states that `bool` is a macro that expands to `_Bool` rather than a typedef.  Regardless, I have not been able to find anything in the C99 standard regarding the size of `_Bool` other than being able to store the values `0` and `1`, so I cannot see anything preventing a standard conforming implementation from making `_Bool` more than one byte.

Comment: If the program was pre-C99 and typedefd `bool` to `int`, that means that the programmer broke the abi by changing the type of `important` from `int` to `_Bool`.

Comment: There are also compiler option for certain architectures that allow the `sizeof (bool)` to be changed at compile time, e.g. Darwin `-mone-byte-bool` changing the default size of 4-bytes to 1-byte.

Answer (score 3):

> Can the change of sizeof(bool) really break old code?

Yes.  Quite easy to find code that *assumes* incorrectly something about the size of `bool` and (lack of)  padding.

> ... there was the `important` member, which was expected to be 1B wide by the code that has set it (hence the 1 zero byte), but at the same time it was expected to be 4B wide (`sizeof int`)

Even if the code was pre-C99, the size of the code defined type of `bool` should have been `sizeof(bool)` or better as `struct Foo f; sizeof(f.important)` and not `sizeof int`.

Further, although code does not show how these sizes were applied, another issues is padding.  Layouts could have been

```
8 byte pointer,  1 byte bool, 7 padding
8 byte pointer,  4 byte bool, 0 padding
8 byte pointer,  4 byte bool, 4 padding
4 byte pointer,  1 byte bool, 3 padding
2 byte pointer,  4 byte bool, 0 padding
etc.
```

Better code would have used `offsetof()` to find the offset and `sizeof(object.member)` to find the size.